Geometric construction of the Laval nozzle
I am performing a LRE calculation and after the calculation I came across the fact that I do not understand how the Laval nozzle is built. I mean, I don't understand how to geometrically create a nozzle profile using data. Tell me how to do this, please


Can you confirm your interest is physically bending metal to form a nozzle (eg design for manufacture), or is this about producing a nozzle curve in a specific CAD or 3D design package?

@GremlinWranger We are talking about creating a contour curve in CAD systems, I do not quite understand how to draw this curve with all the calculated data


Start with point A. Draw a circle around it with the radius rckp.
Draw point C.
Draw a Bezier curve that starts at C with angle theta-a, and ends with a tangent to the circle you drew at step 1, at an angle theta-m.
Draw another circle for the curve on the left side of the throat.

